# Problem with a maximization

Tags: optimization, economics, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am asked to solve the following maximization problem in two variables for my microeconomics class.I know that i must use the KKT conditions  but i have a hard time trying to find a solution.Can anyone help me?
objective function: $f(x; y) = x - \frac{1}{y}$

variables: $x; y$

constraints: $px + wy \leq  m$, $ x \geq 0$, $ y \geq 0$

parameters: $p,w,m$

conditions on parameters:all parameters are strictly positive

Comment: What KKT conditions do you have evaluated so far?

Comment: I  have found a solution which is (x,y)= (0,m/w) but my professor said that the answer has two parts and that the  answer i gave is for m^2<w/p but i cannot understand how he ends up with this restriction.The hypothesis i did for this solution is that x=0,λo=1,λ1>0 but i didn't take into consideration the restriction he says.

Comment: As I said, what are your KKT conditions?